# RavenDb Using Linq to Select based on enum gives Incorrect auto-generated index

Tags: c#, linq, enums, ravendb

The index autogenerated with RavenDB is throwing error.

The main error lines are:

> Line 25, Position 4: Error CS1593 - Delegate 'System.Func>'
>   does not take 1 arguments
>
> Line 29, Position 5: Error CS0833 - An anonymous type cannot have
>   multiple properties with the same name

The full error message is included in the attached file.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var documentStore = new DocumentStore
            {
               Url="http://localhost:8080/databases/test"
            };
        documentStore.Initialize();
        var bookName = "Book";
        using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(new Book
                {
                    Name = bookName,
                    Posts = new List<BookPost> {new BookPost()
                                {
                                    Title = "A post",
                                    Type = BookPost.BookPostType.BooPost1
                                }
                            }
                });

            session.Store(new Book
                {
                    Name = bookName,
                    Posts = new List<BookPost> {new BookPost()
                                {
                                    Title = "A post",
                                    Type = BookPost.BookPostType.BooPost2
                                }
                            }
                });
            session.SaveChanges();
        }

         using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var ravenQueryable = session.Query<Book>().Customize(b=>b.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()).ToList();
        }

        using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var bookToGet = new List<string>() {bookName};
            var bookPostToGet = new List<BookPost.BookPostType?> {BookPost.BookPostType.BooPost1};
            var books = session.Query<Book>().Where(b => b.Name.In(bookToGet));
            books = books.Where(b => b.Posts.Any(p => p.Type.In(bookPostToGet)));

            //****** This line throws an error *********//
            var bookPage = books.ToList();

        }


    }
}

public class Book
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public List<BookPost> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class BookPost
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public BookPostType? Type { get; set; }

    public enum BookPostType
    {
        BooPost1,
        BooPost2,
        BooPost3
    }
}
```

Tried with a more recent: RavenDb build RavenDB.Client.2.5.2666 and RavenDB.Client.2.5.2666.

The full solution (with RavenDb packages : ) is available on my [github](https://github.com/ztthibaut/RavenDbTest.git).

Answer (score -1):

There is a known bug with nullable enums in queries that was fixed in the latest unstable release of RavenDB

Comment: I tried with RavenDB.Client.2.5.2698-Unstable, same issue. Also made the enums non-nullable, had the same error.

Comment: Can you give me the version number you are using? Thanks

Comment: Upgraded to version 2.5.2699-Unstable. Since the previous version, the test passes & not the life version. Am I missing some RavenDB settings?

Comment: Also had to update my Raven server to build 2700 to get it to work.